# Is Microsoft Word 2010 interoperable with Word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007, compatibility

Microsoft provides [a compatibility pack](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/products/microsoft-office-compatibility-pack-for-word-excel-and-powerpoint-HA010168676.aspx) which helps with exchanging files between Office 2007 / 2010 and previous versions of Office.

But it's not clear from the description whether this means that Word 2007 and Word 2010 are completely interoperable - i.e., Can Word 2007 read and edit files created in Word 2010?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes Word 2007 can read from Word 2010. That tool is going from `.docx` (introduced in word 2007) to `.doc` (the standard before 2007), so it is useful for going **from** 2007 or 2010 **to** a version prior to 2007 if the file was saved as a `.docx`. If it was saved as a `.doc` no conversion is required.

Comment: Office 2007 can only read a document provided it doesn't contain any specfic 2010 features.  This of course is the case with any version of Word.